# Trying to push multiple values into array ( Isotope )

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-isotope

I'm using Isotope to function as a categorical organizer of linked content in a fancy layout. I'm trying to push multiple values into an array so it'll display all items touched by the filters. The end result is, however, just displaying the latest item in the array instead of the sum total. Initially, I was pushing all my values into a string, then declaring x as the final result-- I realize this isn't the way to go about this, and have since modified it. Instead of a string, I'm pushing into an array, and hoping to join each value so they'll all be displayed. However, I'm still getting nothing more than the latest selected value. JS as it stands below.

```
  // store filter for each group
  var filters = {};

  $('.filters').on('click', '.button', function() {
    var filters = [];
    // var filters = '';
    var selected = $(this).data('selected');
    var group = $(this).data('group');
    var currentFilter = $(this).data('filter');

    // toggle function along with having multiple selectors
    if(selected == "0") {
      filters.push($(this).data('filter'));
      filters = filters.join(', ');
      // filters = $(this).data('filter');
      $(this).data('selected', "1");
      $(this).addClass('is-checked')
    }
    else {
      $(this).data('selected', "0");
      $(this).removeClass('is-checked')
    }

    // set filter for Isotope
    $grid.isotope({
      filter: filters
    });

    // flatten object by concatting values
    function concatValues(obj) {
      var value = '';
      for (var prop in obj) {
        value += obj[prop];
      }
      return value;
    }
  });
}());
```

I've also set up a [codepen](http://codepen.io/paulkmiller/pen/jWJjbo?editors=1001) for fiddling. Thanks for any suggestions that come. Even pointing me to documentation or tutorials I may have missed would be a great help. For now, I'm studying this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/QsCZx/) that does what I'm shooting for, to see how I can modify my code to better suit what's going on here.

Comment: That code here and the code at codepen are not the same, what gives?

Answer (score 1):

Last week I also spend crazy time with this. :) Luckly I found Desandro's codepen http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/owAyG/ 
Hope that helps.

```
$( function() {

  // filter functions
  var filterFns = {
    greaterThan50: function() {
      var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
      return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
    },
    even: function() {
      var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
      return parseInt( number, 10 ) % 2 === 0;
    }
  };

  // init Isotope
  var $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.color-shape',
    filter: function() {
      var isMatched = true;
      var $this = $(this);

      for ( var prop in filters ) {
        var filter = filters[ prop ];
        // use function if it matches
        filter = filterFns[ filter ] || filter;
        // test each filter
        if ( filter ) {
          isMatched = isMatched && $(this).is( filter );
        }
        // break if not matched
        if ( !isMatched ) {
          break;
        }
      }
      return isMatched;
    }
  });

  // store filter for each group
  var filters = {};

  $('#filters').on( 'click', '.button', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // get group key
    var $buttonGroup = $this.parents('.button-group');
    var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
    // set filter for group
    filters[ filterGroup ] = $this.attr('data-filter');
    // arrange, and use filter fn
    $container.isotope('arrange');
  });

  // change is-checked class on buttons
  $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
      $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
      $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: I came up with a separate solution but this is a great pen. I wish I had seen it before. I'll throw my solution up on my original post.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I ended up with.

I came up with a separate solution but this is a great pen. I wish I had seen it before.

> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {   
> // init Isotope   
> var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
>   itemSelector: '.element-item',
>   layoutMode: 'fitRows',
>   fitRows: {
>     gutter: 27
>   }   
> });
>
> // store filter for each group   
> var filters = [];
>
> $('.filters').on('click', '.button', function() {
>
>   var filterstring = '';
>   var selected = $(this).data('selected');
>   var currentFilter = $(this).data('filter');
>
>
>   // toggle function along with having multiple selectors
>   if (selected == "0") {
>     filters.push( currentFilter );
>     $(this).data('selected', "1");
>     $(this).addClass('is-checked')
>   } else {
>     $(this).data('selected', "0")
>     $(this).removeClass('is-checked')
>
>     var filtername = $(this).data('filter')
>     var i = filters.indexOf(filtername)
>     filters.splice(i, 1)
>   }
>   filterstring = filters.join(', ');
>     // set filter for Isotope
>     $grid.isotope({
>       filter: filters.join("")
>      });   
>    }); 
>  });
> ```